# How to restrict Chinese Character in a textbox ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode

I want to restrict txtObjective (TextBox) to 5 Chinese Character when user is typing Chinese or press btnSaveObjective (Button) to Update the database. I know that Chinese Character is Unicode. How can I restrict it?

Comment: Chinese characters count as English characters (unless you're talking about their, for example, pinyin transliteration) so if can simply limit text box length to five. Do you have to apply different rules when user is not typing in Chinese?

Comment: Hi @Adriano, if it is possible I will like to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

In short you need to allow only English alphabet characters into the textbox-

Try using regex `[\x00-\x80]+` or `[\u0000-\u0080]+`

Comment: Hi, I do not understand what do you meant. Mind typing out a sample out?

Comment: You need to use regular expression validator for the textbox and use `[\x00-\x80]+` or `[\u0000-\u0080]+` as a regular expression